# Plugin for Phonegap/Cordova 3.0 for accessing process indicator in iPhone and Android

Tags: cordova

I've tried all native plugins - push-notifications, notification alerts etc. now I need to work for process indicator. I've also tried with https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins. But I want it for Cordova3.0

Answer (score 1):

Android has a "hidden" progress indicator API: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/blob/master/www/android/notification.js#L47

It doesn't look like there is an equivalent one for iOS though. You might need to just use some javascript progress indicator for now if you can't find a plugin.

I created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5339 to track adding this new feature.

Comment: I am also looking for a plugin for iOS. Infact I easily did with Android. But with iOS, I've least idea(being totally new to iOS).

Answer (score 0):

OK. I finally found out the solution and hence will reply to this.

1)For lymens in iOS like me, progress bar is called progressHud in iOS.

2)The link to the progressHud is  https://github.com/pebois/phonegap-plugin-ProgressHUD.git

3)Just install this plugin via command line arguments and its ready to use :). The .js file has both the method show() and hide(). Just use it :

```
    ProgressHUD.show();
    ProgressHUD.hide();
```